# How make a custom object detection model (cocossd), using just tensorflow and nodejs?

Tags: node.js, tensorflowjs

I need a turorial about how to create a object detection, using tensorflowjs and nodejs, no browser, no python... is this posible, i tried to start doing this but i get a lot o bugs... so i need a guide line to acomplish this.

I start doing this

```
const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs')
const cc = require('@tensorflow-models/coco-ssd');
require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node')

cc.load()
```

and this get me this error.

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: tfconv.loadGraphModel is not a function

Answer (score 1):

`cc.load()` returns a promise. So you have to use cc.load().then({ ... your code}) or `await cc.load()`. Read the official docs of coco ssd for more information